# Hide included layout in android

Tags: android, include, android-relativelayout

I have to develop an android application.

I have created one layout file that uses another layout file using the `include` tag.

```
  <include
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    layout="@layout/footer_tabs" />
  <include
    android:id="@+id/footer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    layout="@layout/footertabs" />
```

I would like to show the included layout when a response is null, otherwise I would like to hide the layout and show the other. Here is what I have so far:

```
footertabs = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.footertab);
footer_tabs = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.footer_tab);

if (Constants.response==null) {
    footertabs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    footer_tabs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else
{
    footertabs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    footer_tabs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
07-15 17:19:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(15143): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 17:19:09.893: E/AndroidRuntime(15143):    at com.example.androidbestinuk.HomePage.onCreate(HomePage.java:56)
```

Please help me debug this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should change

```
footertabs = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.footertab);
footer_tabs = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.footer_tab);
```

with

```
footertabs = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.footer);
footer_tabs = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.footer1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it appears to me that you're using the wrong id's. You're getting a null pointer somewhere (I'm not sure where because there are no line numbers), but I see in your xml you have id's, `footer` and `footer1`, but in your code you are trying to find elements with id's `footertab`, and `footer_tab`. You should make these id's match.

Answer (score 0):

Using ViewBinding and Kotlin, it can be achieved this way

```
binding.yourInclude.root.visibility = View.GONE
```

For specific views inside `<include>` tag use code below

```
binding.yourInclude.textView.visibility = View.GONE
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this is some useful code, it doesn't answer the question of the original author...